# WooCommerce pre_get_posts

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

So I've used `pre_get_posts` in my `functions.php` before and it works like a charm, but for some reason I can't figure out why it's not working for a WooCommerce page `archive-product.php` I have.

Directory Structure:

```
.
├──woocommerce
|   ├── archive-product.php
├── functions.php
```

Inside `functions.php`:

```
function specific_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '7815' );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'specific_category' );
```

Inside `archive-product.php`:

```
var_dump($wp_query); //this should be the main query variable but doesn't exist.
```

Then I tried this inside `archive-product.php`:

```
global $wp_query;

foreach($wp_query->posts as $k){
    print_r($k);
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Which does output posts but the posts aren't relative to the category set in the `functions.php` code `$query->set( 'cat', '7815' );`

**Question:** Why am I having to declare `global $wp_query` (it should be initialize by default) and why aren't the post from the category I selected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in a page, the query you're seeing is the category with one page that's basically the page you're seeing. Its not a list of posts as you expected to see on the homepage.

if you have a normal blog-style homepage and you check the query you can see `[found_posts] => 4`. but try to set a 'page' as homepage and check your query. You can see `[found_posts] => 1` and that one found item (post/page) in your query is the current one.

You can try to add a custom query with Wordpress `WP_Query` class in your Page Template and it gives you a lot of options too.

Also, if you're trying to check for a homepage that is showing a page, consider using `is_front_page()`.

and for your other question about declaring `$wp_query`, unfortunately I don't have an answer.